# Enabling custom errors creates runtime error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, error-handling

I'm trying to redirect all my 404 errors to the Index page of my project. 
But when I set my custom errors in web.config I get a Runtime Error that says:
"An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated. "
Here is my web.config errors block.

```
<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" >
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/" />
  </customErrors>
```

I would appreciate any suggestions how to debug and fix it.

Comment: Sounds like your redirect is not working as intended, or the index page is throwing an error as well..  Put a breakpoint early in the index page and see if it gets hit.

Comment: Why are you redirecting 404s to the home page anyways?  Why not just use a custom 404 page to indicate that there was a problem?

Comment: On the development environment, can you attach to the IIS worker process (w3wp), activate the [exceptions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/02/23/the-new-exception-settings-window-in-visual-studio-2015/) and see if it stop when the exception is thrown. Also, Event Viewer might provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

Your redirect is empty. Try adding a new custom error page and change the redirect to something like `redirect="~/Controller/CustomerErrorPage"`